# Angular velocity vector from linear velocity vector

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors, angular-velocity

Linear velocity vector is $\vec{v}$ and the distance vector is $\vec{r} $.

How is it that angular velocity vector is $\vec{ω}$ =  $\frac {\vec{r} × \vec{v}}{|\vec{r}|^2}$

The equation I am aware of is  $\vec{v}$ $=$ $\vec{r}×\vec{ω}$. I tried taking a dot product on both sides, cross product etc but I wasn't able to derive the above equation. How is it possible ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The triple vector-product identity gives
$$
{\bf r}\times {\bf v}= {\bf r}\times({\boldsymbol \omega}\times {\bf r} )=-({\boldsymbol \omega}\cdot {\bf r}){\bf r}+ |{\bf r}|^2 {\boldsymbol \omega}. $$
But $({\boldsymbol \omega}\cdot {\bf r})$ is not necessarily zero, and so in general
${\boldsymbol \omega}\ne ({\bf r}\times {\bf v})/|r|^2$. It's only true if ${\bf r}$ is perpendicular to ${\boldsymbol \omega}$

In my original answer I miscopied fom a piece of paper and had $-({\boldsymbol \omega}\cdot {\bf v}){\bf r}$ in the first term, and this *is* zero, but wrong!

Answer (score 4):

The correct definition of linear velocity is $\vec{v} = \vec{\omega}\times\vec{r}$ and your relation for $\vec{\omega}$ is then a simple application of the vector triple product, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_product.

(Or the other way around if you prefer that.)

Edit: As @mikestone correctly notes in his answer this is only valid for circular motion where the position vector is orthogonal to the angular velocity vector.

Comment: I made an error in my answer! It is not generally true that $\omega= r\times v/|r|^2$. You should probably undo the green tick of approval you gave me!

Comment: @mikestone I think you meant this to be a comment to the question, right? Furthermore, i gave a similar answer to you. So this would also invalidate mine. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I edited my anwer, forgot to save it, and then wrote my comment. I have now, at last,  put what I believe to be correct answer!